# MVC 5 Session not presisted when going to another View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller

Session variable lost after a controller calls another View to render.

```
public ActionResult Index(Customer model, string cancel, string effective)
{
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cancel))
  {
    //update database
    Session["variable2"] = new Info(){ Text = "Do not processed"};
    return View("Cancelation");  //error stated occurs when calling another view
  }
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(effective)
  {
     //do data base update
    Session["variable1"] = new Info(){ Text = "Processed"};
    return View(model); //All good here
  }
{
```

I have a MVC controller that when post back to it I set a Session variable "variable1", then I do return View(model). In this case all is good I can access the new Session variable1 everywhere.

But when I post back to the same controller again, I check the button clicked and then I set another Session variable, "variable2" this time I do return `View("Cancelation")`.

This last variable2 is lost and does not show on `HttpContext.Current.Session["variable2"]` anywhere in the application.

Can someone help to understand why?

Comment: Can you post controller code?

Comment: Post it as an answer then, when you're able, accept it for future visitors with same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that because I was using SQL Server as Session store, I had to use Serialize() attribute on the object, then it worked.